# what will be the space complexity of the following?

Tags: space-complexity

if two vectors are used for ex,
vector<vector> temp;
vector temp2;

then what will be the space complexity, will it be O(n) or O(n^2)?

Comment: I think you need to give additional details as to how you are going to use these vectors when you get the input.

Comment: @Russel: how you use the vectors does not determine the space complexity.

Comment: I was just thinking that maybe it will be use not just for storing the $n$ inputs but for storing the result of some computation, whose size is some function of the input size.

Comment: @Russel: I see, that makes sense. And indeed the question is much too vague. In fact, we don't even know what $n$ is.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of `temp` will be

$$\sum_{i=1}^n v_i$$ where $n$ denotes the size of the outer vector and the $v_i$ are the sizes of the inner vectors.

Space complexities are in principle given in terms of units of storage.